# Create singleton object which implements 2 interfaces

Tags: koin

```
single<ObserveLifeCycleState> { Communicator( domain = get(), repositoryMessanger = get() ) }

single<NewMessageListener> { Communicator( domain = get(), repositoryMessanger = get() ) }
```

As you can see I am instantiating the same 2 objects because it implements both interfaces. But this creates 2 different objects. How can I do it with only one initialization?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 single {
        Communicator(
            domain = get(),
            repositoryMessanger = get()
        )
    }
    single {
        val communicator: Communicator = get()

        communicator as NewMessageListener
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idiomatic way of binding a single instance to multiple interfaces.

```
single { 
    Communicator(get(), get())
}
single<NewMessageListener> { 
    get<Communicator>()
}
single<ObserveLifeCycleState> {
    get<Communicator>()
}
```